# Route model binding doesn't working in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on a small project where I have a `User Model` containing the user data. I can access data from my `Model` by using eloquent `ORM` in my route. Now I want to access my data with `Route Model Binding`. I have tried following

In my `RouteServiceProvider`

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);
    $router->model('user', 'App\User');
}
```

And in my `Route File`

```
Route::get('check_bind/{user}',function(App\User $user)
{
      return $user;
});
```

But when i give the url `http://localhost:8000/check_bind/1`, I get nothing but `[]`.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with using `$router->model()` before, returning an empty model. Not sure if that's what's happening here.

What happens when you do:

```
Route::get('check_bind/{user}',function(App\User $user)
{
     dd($user);
});
```

Do you get an empty user model? i.e. no attributes?

And what if instead of `$router->model()` in the service provider you do:

```
Route::bind('user', function($value)
{
    return App\User::find($value);
});
```

Comment: I have done the both but it returns following                                                  User {#227 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
}

Comment: When using `Route::bind('user', function($value) { return App\User::find($value); });` Can you dd() the `$value` and the return value ?

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this issue and deleting your vendor folder and running composer install did the trick.